# How to find this angle in a circle segment?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I'm stuck trying to get $\nu$. I need it for knowing another angle but I can't see the relation in there. I've tried using the height of the chord, the angle between the point P and and the center of the circungerence..., but nothing works.

In black the data I have to get $\nu$: {$R, \alpha, d$}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value $\alpha$ is not needed. To find $\nu$, you could draw some additional lines to create a right-angled triangle with $R$ as its diagonal and $d$ as one of the other sides.

[image]

As you can see in the diagram, we have $\nu = \arcsin(d/R)$.